# how to over ride some of tinymce's methods - specially render

Tags: django, tinymce, render, django-tinymce

i wanna override TinyMCE's render method
i want to use a button beside TinyMCE for some reason, 
i'v written some lines, but it does no effect:

this is my class:

```
class UpdateTinyMCE(TinyMCE):
    def render(self, *args, **kwargs):
    html = super(UpdateTinyMCE, self).render(*args, **kwargs)
    return mark_safe(html + '<input type="button" value="submit" />')
```

and this is the usage:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Article
    exclude = ['slug', 'rating', 'numberOfRates', 'isCommentApproval', 'maximumRate']
    widgets = {
        'renderType': Select(attrs={'onChange': 'changeRenderType();' }),
        'content':UpdateTinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 100, 'rows': 30})
    }
```

Comment: Could you include the rendered html just before it is returned from `render`? Is it exactly the same using both `UpdateTinyMCE` and `TinyMCE`?

Comment: actually, i'v used the right way